# How do I create array conformed to ObservableObject?

Tags: swift, environment, observedobject

```
class Group: ObservableObject {
    @Published var size: CGFloat = 22
}

struct content: View {
    @ObservedObject var groups: [Group] = []
    var body: some view {
        .
        .
        .
  }
}
```

above code error message :

> Referencing initializer 'init(wrappedValue:)' on 'ObservedObject'
>   requires that '[Group]' conform to 'ObservableObject'

I need array conformed to `ObservableObject` because i need to detect size property of Group in [Group]

How to make array of `ObservableObject(ObservedObject)`

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure how to solve this problem directly but one way to solve your problem would be something like a GroupStore which holds your array. That could look like this:

```
class GroupStore: ObservableObject {

    @Published private(set) var groups: [Group] = []
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And then in your View you add the GroupStore property like this:

```
struct content: View {

    @ObservedObject var groupStore: GroupStore
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Thx for ur answer. But one problem ur code. When changed property size of group, content not detect chaned group because Group is not struct but class. Am i wrong?

Comment: so sorry i need detect size property of Group in [Group].